# Websocket server as service on Azure?

Tags: android, ios, azure, websocket, push-notification

I have a websocket based app and I am running my own NodeJS server acting as the websocket server. I would typically like to hive this off to a managed service and avoid running my own websocket server. So I dont have to worry about scaling and downtime. Does AZURE provide a hosted websocket service that I can use?

I am also interested in how I can build a publishing mechanism (Sending Push Notifications to Android and iOS apps) with some service managed by AZURE ?

Comment: try pusher . https://pusher.com/pricing

Comment: StackOverflow != Google

Answer (score 1):

[Notification Hubs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/notification-hubs/) may be exactly what you need for the mobile scenario (pushing notifications to iOS and Android).

For Websockets, understanding the scenario better would help.

If you need straight-up websockets, [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) runs nicely under NodeJS in App Services. Be sure to [enable Websockets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/introduction-to-websockets-on-windows-azure-web-sites/) in the App Service configuration otherwise it will fall back to long polling.

If you'd like some Pub/Sub infrastructure, [Event Grid](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/event-grid/) or Service Bus Topics could be a good solution. They're PaaS services and easy to deploy. Event Grid is better for lighter-weight reactive/serverless scenarios and Service Bus Topics are great for large-scale enterprise scenarios where you need queuing and other more advanced integrations.

Comment: Thanks  a lot for your description. I think I'll go with Socket.IO for websockets.